# WanaDecryptor КиберАтака. Можно ли получить ключ шифрования, если шифрование продолжается

Tags: безопасность, шифрование, криптография, вирусы

Зараженная система Windows 7.  Этот троян шифровальщик, который сегодня 
 поразил множество почти никак не связанных сетей, предлагает перезагрузить комп и при загрузке шифрует всякие пользовательские данные. Вероятно ключ генерируется для компа один.  Хотя сам exe файл вируса есть в каждой папке.  Хотят в биткоинах 300 баксов, чтобы те как то связались и выслали ключ.  Возможно при шифровке ключ как то отправляется им.  В сети пишут, что снифер мог бы помочь.  Какие можно придумать способы узнать ключ? Если создать тестовый файл например, после перезагрузки можно его уже обнаружить зашифрованным.  Оригинал файла скорее всего удаляется.  Вирус чистит теневые файлы,  точек восстановления нет. Сам вирус можно удалить но это не поможет расшифровке.  Пытаться сканировать жесткий диск чтобы восстановить оригинальные файлы можно если диск был не сильно заполнен и вероятность того, что шифрованные файлы не записались сверху, низкая.

Comment: Я полагаю во время шифрования ключ получить практически невозможно, если даже сканировать работу шифровальщика.  Но возможно во время расшифровки. На эти мысли наталкиваюсь читая статьи про акустический анализ ключей или электромагнитный анализ.  Но факт того что троян по окончанию шифровки пытается отправить ключ, дает пока мне надежду

Comment: Если он не отправил ключ в самом начале. было бы логично. сгенерил пару ключей, приватный сразу отправил и забыл, а публичным шифруешь ключи от какого нибудь симметричного шифра каждого файла. Собственно что вам даст ключ. для начала надо выяснить используемый алгоритм(ы) шифрования, а потом исходя из этого думать о ключах. Если шифр симметричный, то значит ключ есть в момент выполнения шифровщика в его данных, загонять под отладку, изучать алгоритм, искать ключ.

Comment: Чем отлаживать?  Не занимался этим.

Comment: Тогда вряд ли у вас что то выйдет. требуются хорошие знания ассемблера. Так что можете попробовать расшифровщики от каспеского и drweb. правда на данный момент они скорее всего еще не умеют работать с этой версией вируса. по крайней мере позавчера один комп пытались лечить, они не помогли.

Comment: А что толку расшифровывать, то что AES или RSA зашифровано? есть смысл только во время очередной шифровки ключ ловить, зная что каждый раз он один и тот же на этом компьютере. А так называемый реверс инженеринг не поможет понять алгоритм по которому создается ключ для шифровки, может это не совсем рандом

Comment: Какая разница как он создается. в момент шифрования готовый ключ лежит в оперативной памяти процесса, который шифрует. по алгоритму можно понять где именно он лежит и забрать его.

Comment: но для начала надо узнать какой именно алгоритм используется, ибо в ключе никакого толка, если не ясно как его применять. А что до снифера, то кто мешает вирусу при передаче его использовать ssl на канале и тогда вы его не увидите

Comment: думаю если быть уверенным что ключ получен правильно можно попробовать его использовать для разных дэшефраторов . Наверняка что то популярное AES , RSA или какой нибудь гибридный

Comment: в общем я понял ваш ответ, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Объясняю, WannaCry(вторая версия) через сеть **[Tor](https://wikiless.org/wiki/Tor_(network))** подключается к onion северу, а уже на сервере создаётся ключ для конкретного пользователя, соответственно ключ хранится на сервере и на клиенте жертвы никак ключ дешифровки не получить, к примеру у шифровальщика Jigsaw ключ создаётся, и сохраняется на стороне клиента и клиент может декомпилировать его и в отдельной подкатегории в файле хранится ключ его можно ввести и расшифровать свои файлы.